# Going to graduate school in applied mathematics without having taken a topology course?

Tags: soft-question

Due to a critical course conflict, I won't be able to take any topology or geometry courses before I graduate. However, I plan to go to graduate school in [applied] mathematics. Will this hinder me significantly in admissions? I am sure it will not need to hinder me in my studies itself as I will just teach myself the material of a basic course before graduate school, if necessary and enroll in a topology course once I get to graduate school.

Comment: I would say that it's all about what you want to research.  Does your intended research need any tools from topology?

Comment: Must one have a specific research project in mind when applying? I hope to do research in mathematical/computational molecular biochemistry, but I don't know exactly what I would like to research. It is certainly possible that a research project in this area might involve topology, but I don't know what exactly I want to do yet.

Comment: I don't think one needs to have a specific project in mind when applying to grad school, but it's not a bad idea to know what general field interests you.  It might be a decent idea to look up papers in molecular biochemistry and see if they use anything from topology (my guess is that they probably don't, but I could be wrong).  Learning the subject certainly can't hurt.  The question might be how diligently/methodically you should go through a topology text.  Just for reference [this](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/) is a really good introductory book.